# PHP image resampling issue

Tags: php, gd

When i resample a jpg in order to draw border around the image, the quality of image is horribly decreases and extremely low quality jpeg is gotten. 
[image]

Here is my code:

```
function addBorderpng($add,$bdr=0,$color='#000000'){
                $arr = explode('.', $add);
                $extension = strtolower(end($arr));
                $border=$bdr;

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg($add);

                $width=imagesx($im);
                $height=imagesy($im);
                $img_adj_width=$width+(2*$border);
                $img_adj_height=$height+(2*$border);
                $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($img_adj_width,$img_adj_height);

                imageantialias($newimage, true);
                $color_gb_temp =HexToRGB($color);
                $border_color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, $color_gb_temp['r'], $color_gb_temp['g'], $color_gb_temp['b']);
                imagefilledrectangle($newimage,0,0,$img_adj_width,$img_adj_height,$border_color);
                imagealphablending($newimage, true);
                imageantialias($newimage, true);
                     imagecopyresized($newimage,$im,$border,$border,0,0,$width,$height,$width,$height);
                    imagejpeg($newimage,$add,9);
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last argument to [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) is quality.

> quality is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75).

You are setting it at 9, hence low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can try "imagecopyresampled" in place of "imagecopyresized" which handles interpolation[PHP imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)